# Is there a way to prevent (have everything but) specific characters in "match" in .tmLanguage

Tags: tmlanguage

As the title said, is there a way to prevent specific characters in "match" in .tmLanguage syntax highlighting? Like, for example, match everything but w and s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `[^ws]` is what you're looking for. `^` is a regex negation operator. So, just like you'd use `[abc]` to match either a, b, or c, adding `^` at the beginning negates it. Just make sure it's inside the square brackets.